# shopping cart session array

Tags: php, session, session-variables, shopping-cart

When user click on the add button, the product id are stored into the session array.

See Code below:

```
Array
(

    [storeID] => 123
    [10] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [product_id] => 2
            [extras_id] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 12
            [product_id] => 2
            [extras_id] => Array
                (
                   8
                )

        )
)
```

As you can see 10 and 20 is option_id from the product_id = 2

User can select number of options from a specific product.

User can select extras (or without) from option

Is this array good design or how can it be improved?

Example:

```
Product (2): Burger
- Option (10): Large (User not selected any extra)
- Option (20): Small (User selected coke(8) as extra)
```

User selected ID 10 and 20 for burger.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with it, except that you could get it more "organized", this way:

```
Array
(
    [123] => array(
        [2] => array(
            [10] => array(
                [quantity] => '',
                [extras] => ''
            ),
            [20] => array(
                [quantity] => '',
                [extras] => ''
            )
        )       
    )
)
```

But that's just my opinion and my way to think.

Answer (score 1):

What if product 3 also has option 10?

I'd go for using product's as the key, and adding quantity, options and extras an subs of that array.

This setup does assume you can't add the same product more then once, even if the extra's do not match. Another poster suggest adding an combination of extras/options/productid, which is good. If that's the case, please upvote him :).

```
Array
(
    'cart' => array(
        'storeid' => 123,
        'products' => array(
            2 => array(
              'quantity' => 2,
              'options' => array(10, 20),
              'extras' => array(2)
            ),
            3 => array(
              'quantity' => 12,
              'options' => array(150, 20),
              'extras' => array(1, 7)
            )
        )       
    )
)
```

Comment: I think extras look wrong?  Option 10 can have extras but not option 20.

Comment: I see, extras are part of the option, not the product. correct?

Comment: Correct. Each product has number of options. Each option can have exreas or without exras

Answer (score 0):

What I prefer is to store products in this format:

```
Array
(
    [md5 hash of (product id + serialized array of selected options)] => Array
        (
            'qty' => 10
            'title' => 'Product XYZ'
            'price' => 49.99
            'options' => Array
                (
                   ...
                )
        )
)
```

That gives each cart item it's own "id", easily allowing you to modify data for each cart item, such as qty, if you need to.

**Edited:**

This is a trimmed down example of what my cart's items array looks like:
*7483f8f0007eb9ef3ddb8d2bff606bd6* and *859d1bb225ba5d16de4d4c23076cfae0* are both md5 hashes created by `md5($itemId.serialize($submittedOptions))`.

```
Array
(
    [7483f8f0007eb9ef3ddb8d2bff606bd6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [qty] => 2
            [price] => 20.00
            [title] => Product XYZ
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [photo] => /uploads/media/products/product_xyz.jpg
                    [link] => /product/3-product-xyz/
                    [sku] => PRODUCT-XYZ
                    [weight] => 10
                    [attributes] => Array
                        (
                            ...
                        )

                )

        )

    [859d1bb225ba5d16de4d4c23076cfae0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [qty] => 2
            [price] => 30.00
            [title] => Product XYZ
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [photo] => /uploads/media/products/product_xyz.jpg
                    [link] => /product/3-product-xyz/
                    [sku] => PRODUCT-XYZ
                    [weight] => 15
                    [attributes] => Array
                        (
                            ...
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I dont understand this part: md5 hash of (product id + serialized array of selected options). And what if an option has extras?

Comment: Product does not come with price, each option has a price. I think your array design is quite wrong.

Comment: Define "option" and "extras".  Also, I'm updating my answer to provide an example.

Comment: Also, no my design is not wrong.  When the "add product to cart" form is submitted, the product controller calculates the total cost of the product, including chosen options, and submits a single price to the cart model.  The cart model does not care what different product options cost. It only needs a single price to display to the user when the cart is displayed.

Comment: Each product has number of options. Each option can have extras or without extra. Option and exras has prices

Comment: Ok, so when the add to cart form is submitted, calculate the total cost for that product based on the user's selections, and submit that cost to the cart model.  What I call "attributes", you call "options". I don't have "extras" for options, but there is nothing stopping you from adding an array for each option for the chosen extras.  The main thing to remember though is that everything within each "data" key is solely "extra" information that the Cart does not care about.  It only needs a qty and total price to do what it needs.